# jquery equivalent of preload="auto" in html?

Tags: function, onload, pageload, jquery

I have the script in html which plays sound when page ABC loads:

```
<audio id="s"><source src=".../s.wav" preload="auto"/></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">var sample = document.getElementById("s"); sample.play(); s.volume='1';</script>
```

How `preload="auto"` functionality can be achieved in jquery?

Comment: `xxx.attr('preload','auto') ?`

Comment: thanks. for others who might need this, here is the complete solution for class="aaa": $('.aaa').attr('preload','auto', sample.play())

Comment: what is that callback function syntax? I dont think it's supported.

Comment: I've just tested on my pages and it works. But I'm curious, what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: `('.aaa').attr('preload','auto').promise().done(function (){sample.play()});  ` or just write the line in a new line.

Comment: ('.aaa').attr('preload','auto'); (new line) sample.play();